# How to initialize a class with async

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I'm making a profile page with Flutter in Dart. User information is stored in Firebase Firestore and an image is stored in Firebase Storage. Firestore contains profile image's path in Firebase Storage (`profileImages/{userId}/profile.jpg`). As you can see my code below, downloadable image url is gotten in `ProfileImage` class.

I'd like to `getDownloadUrl` when initializing User class. Not in ProfileImage class.

```dart
class User {
  final profilePathInFirebaseStorage;
  User({this.profilePathInFirebaseStorage});
  factory User.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return User(profilePathInFirebaseStorage: snapshot.data['imagePath']);
  }
}

class ProfileImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String profilePathInFirebaseStorage;

  const ProfileImage(
      {Key key,
      this.profilePathInFirebaseStorage = '',)
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref(profilePathInFirebaseStorage)
            .getDownloadURL(),  // Can this operation go into User class?
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
          return Container(child: NetworkImage(snapshot.data));
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can't you just add a method to your `User` class that returns the result of the `getDownloadURL()` call?

Comment: Thank you for a comment. I don't want to call `getDownloadUrl()` every time when showing profile image. It's not effective. So I want `User` instance keep downloadable URL. I think it should be done when initializing a user instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't have an async constructor, here's a pattern for creating your `User` class using an async static method.

```
class User {
  String userData;

  User._privateConstructor();

  static Future<User> createAsync() async {
    var user = User._privateConstructor();
    print('User.createAsync() called');
    return user._initAsync();
  }

  /// Simulates a long-loading process such as remote DB connection or device
  /// file storage access.
  Future<User> _initAsync() async {
    // ↓ do your Firebase call here ↓
    userData = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => 'Some Firebase user data');
    print('User._initAsync done');
    return this;
  }
}
```

To instantiate your `User` class, call the exposed async method:

```
User user = await User.createAsync();
```

When this returns your `user` instance will have Firestore data it needs.

Example in a `StatefulWidget` with `FutureBuilder` (not using `await`):

```
class ProfileImagePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileImagePageState createState() => _ProfileImagePageState();
}

class _ProfileImagePageState extends State<ProfileImagePage> {
  Future<User> user;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    user = User.createAsync();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: FutureBuilder<User>(
          future: user,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData)
                return Center(child: Text(snapshot.data.userData),);
              else
                return Center(child: Text('Loading...'));
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to store the download URL in the user class, and then only initialize once.

Something like this should work:

```
class User {
  final profilePathInFirebaseStorage;
  Future<String> downloadURL
  User({this.profilePathInFirebaseStorage});
  factory User.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return User(profilePathInFirebaseStorage: snapshot.data['imagePath']);
  }

  Future<String> getDownloadURL() {
    if (downloadURL == null) {
      downloadURL = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref(profilePathInFirebaseStorage)
            .getDownloadURL()
    }
    return downloadURL;
  }
}
```

So this initializes the download URL on demand, the first time it is requested. You could do the same in the constructor if you want. But there's no way to make it not a `Future` as the download URL is determined asynchronously, and you need a `Future` to handle the case where somebody requests the URL before it's available.

Comment: Thank you. How would you initialize it and set downloadable URL?

Comment: Thank you. Could you complete your code including constructor/factory method ? I want to be sure that I understand perfectly.